# How do i find the average value of a particular column which has date datatype in oracle? And i want the average to be NUMBER datatype

Tags: sql, database, oracle, transactions, average

Let say i have this table and i have inserted alot of date into it.

```
CREATE TABLE dateOfTransaction(
    TransDATE  DATE  NOT NULL);
```

I need to convert the Transdate to number datatype first? then do

```
SELECT AVG(TransDate) FROM dateOfTransaction;
```

Comment: How do you average dates together?  What is the algorithm that you want to use?  And what number do you want to be returned?

Comment: I think you need to re-consider what you mean by 'average' when thinking of a date. Do you mean the most common date, i.e. the mode, the middle value of the range, i.e. median, or something else ? What information is that value trying to communicate to us ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what that "average date" is, but - just for fun - have a look at his:

Set date format (to see what is what):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table dateoftransaction
  2    (transdate date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into dateoftransaction
  2    select sysdate from dual union all
  3    select date '2018-11-23' from dual union all
  4    select to_date('30.09.2025 13:32:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from dateoftransaction;

TRANSDATE
-------------------
13.11.2019 20:59:00
23.11.2018 00:00:00
30.09.2025 13:32:33

SQL>
```

Average date is - of course - invalid:

```
SQL> select avg(transdate) from dateoftransaction;
select avg(transdate) from dateoftransaction
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

But, what if we convert it to a **Julian** date?

```
SQL> select transdate, to_char(transdate, 'J') julian_date from dateoftransaction;

TRANSDATE           JULIAN_
------------------- -------
13.11.2019 20:59:00 2458801
23.11.2018 00:00:00 2458446
30.09.2025 13:32:33 2460949
```

That is a number, and yes - we know how to calculate average value on numbers, right?

```
SQL> select
  2                  avg(to_number(to_char(transdate, 'J')))          avg_julian_date,
  3    to_date(trunc(avg(to_number(to_char(transdate, 'J')))), 'JSP') avg_date
  4  from dateoftransaction;

AVG_JULIAN_DATE AVG_DATE
--------------- -------------------
     2459398,67 02.07.2021 00:00:00
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract a base date, take the average, and add back to the base:

```
select date '2000-01-01' + avg(dateOfTransaction - date '2000-01-01') * interval '1 day'
```